# SVN checkout filtered by file extension?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I have a home-grown automated build script in the form of a DOS batch file.  In part of that script, I check out (with "svn checkout") a section of our SVN repository that includes a bunch of third-party stuff that's used in our projects.  This batch file performed pretty well for a long time, but now people have checked in lots of fluff (docs, sample code, etc.) into the third-party area and the checkout part of this script has gotten lots slower.  I'd like to mitigate this by checking out only the stuff we need -- mostly dll files in our case.  So, my question is this: what's the best way to check out an SVN repository filtered by file extension?

I didn't see any obvious way to do this in the svn help.  I have a .NET utility library that wraps svn.exe in some ways, and I was thinking of extending this to retrieve only content that matched my extensions of interest.  But I'd prefer to use an easier or existing method if one exists.

Comment: This is too localized. The question is referring to third party svn adds

Comment: @AlxVallejo No, it's not.  It's referring to svn.exe.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is possible: you can `svn checkout` an empty directory, and then `svn update filename` for each file that you *do* want.

Your script can do something like:

1. `svn checkout svn://path/to/repos/directory --depth empty`
2. `svn list --recursive svn://path/to/repos/directory`
3. Pipe that result through a filter that removes the forbidden file extensions, e.g. `grep`
4. Iterate over this new filtered list and `svn update --parents` each file

That would give your desired result of a working copy without certain files or file extensions.

Of course, there is also the issue that you mention of “people [checking] in lots of fluff” but that’s a separate matter.

Comment: You might want to also have a look at ant's subversion support:
 http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html

Comment: what does an implementation of this look like?

Comment: I tried implementing this approach myself but I think I'm doing it wrong.  I'm getting skipped path conflicts.

Comment: @Pup to get all text files, #2-#4 is a 1-liner... `svn up \`svn list svn://svn.foo.com:3690/svn/somerepo/somedir/ | grep txt\``... you can just use #2 in backticks to use the resulting list of txt files right to `svn up[date]`.

Answer (score 3):

As I told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192824/svn-checkout-ignore-folder), there is only one option build into SVN itself: A new feature in SVN 1.5 called **sparse checkout**, however you can only select checkout on directory level, so you have to sort the files you do not need in a different directory.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to Sparse Directories - they are really powerful feature. For all interested http://bit.ly/99Nblk is the relevant chapter from svn-book.

Comment: So in other words, no there's no way to filter an svn checkout by extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check out just a few specific files -- you can only check out a whole folder.  You can rearrange the organization of what you're checking out, or you can just copy a working copy from somewhere else and update.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the approach presented by Michael Hackner. Below is the implementation for a DOS system. Note that you have to to checkout the empty folder before running this script.

```
@echo off

svn list --recursive https://path_to_repository_folder | find /I ".sql" > filelist.txt

REM Specify a custom delim. Otherwise space in filename will be treated as a delimiter.
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i  IN (filelist.txt) DO (
    echo -------------
    echo %%i
    svn update --parents "%%i"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

For a powershell specific implementation of the answer from [Michael Hackner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189919/michael-hackner), try something like:

```
svn ls http://svn-server/src --recursive | Out-File svn.txt
Get-Content .\svn.txt | where {$_.toLower().EndsWith('special.xml')} | select -First 200 | foreach {New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Path = $_; Munged = $_.Replace('/', '_') } } | foreach { svn export "http://svn-server/src/$($_.Path)" $($_.Munged) }
```

My particular use case here is finding a bunch of similarly named files (in this case *special.xml) and dumping them all into a single folder, with essentially unique names. I have used an intermediate file to store the entire repo listing, but this could all be inlined as well if that's better for you.

Answer (score -4):

The most simple and a correct way to do this: DON'T DO IT!

If there is some crap in third party folder where there suppose to be .dll files that needs to be checkout - remove that crap to a different location! It does not belong here anyway.