# SVN checkout ignore folder

Tags: svn, build-automation, cruisecontrol.net, svn-checkout

Can I ignore a folder on svn checkout? I need to ignore DOCs folder on checkout at my build server.

**edit:** Ignore externals isn't an option. I have some externals that I need.

Comment: Check out this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I ignore a directory with SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can't directly ignore folders on a checkout, but you can use sparse checkouts in svn 1.5.  For example:

```
$ svn co http://subversion/project/trunk my_checkout --depth immediates
```

This will check files and directories from your project trunk into 'my_checkout', but not recurse into those directories.  Eg:

```
$ cd my_checkout && ls
bar/ baz foo xyzzy/
```

Then to get the contents of 'bar' down:

```
$ cd bar && svn update --set-depth infinity
```

Comment: Note: there was a bug in some 1.5 versions that prevented this with `svn: Shallowing of working copy depths is not yet supported`

Answer (score 82):

Yes you can using SVN 1.6. You will need to do a checkout first then mark the folder for exclusion then delete the unwanted folder.

```
svn checkout http://www.example.com/project
cd project
svn update --set-depth=exclude docs
rm -fr docs
```

From now on any updates to the working copy won't repopulate the docs folder.

See http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2009/03/sparse-directories-now-with-exclusion/ and http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#sparse-directory-exclusion for more details.

Tom

Comment: Upvoted because it saved me from having to checkout an enormous folder that wasn't relevant to my work.

Comment: That's great, together with [svn cleanup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21028557/1904815) this saved me 12 GiB.

Comment: Doesn't this still checkout everything initially?

Answer (score 9):

With versions prior to 1.5 I have found that if you checkout only the top most folder and then selectively update, from then on updates only effect what you have checked out. Ie.

```
svn co -N foo
cd foo
svn up -N bar
svn up
```

The -N flag makes the operation non-recursive. The above will not check out anything else at the foo level, eg. say there is a folder `lala`, the final svn up will not check out that folder, but it will update `bar`.

But at a later time you can `svn up lala` and thus, add it to the checkout.

Presumably this also works with 1.5.

Answer (score 6):

This is in TortoiseSVN client 1.7.1 (might be available in some older versions as well):

- SVN checkout --> Select URL of repository
- Click on "Checkout Items" (under Checkout Depth) and select only the
  folders required!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [Subversion 1.5](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.5.html) has a feature called [Sparse checkouts](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.5.html#sparse-checkouts) that can do exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: From reading that, it looks like sparse checkouts only limit the depth of a checkout. They can't ignore one particular folder.

Comment: Sure, you might have to do a little extra legwork, like limit the depth of the parent folder with --depth immediates, then check out all the other folders except the one you would like to ignore. The point is, the tools are there if you need to use them.

Comment: I appreciate the mention of SparseCheckouts, and it is interesting for sure, but this response does not address the original question.  Sure, I can check out one file at a time, and that will result in having local copies of specific files I want, but what a pain in the ass to have to do each individually.  I believe the author of this question is asking about ignoring a specific folder, not depth of x folders, and allow the computer do the work - the same work you are recommending could be accomplished manually.

Comment: The 1.6+ versions provide the added ability to ignore folders and more control general of what to include/exclude in a working copy (where v1.5 is very limited in this) http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html

Answer (score 4):

You could put the docs folder in an external repository and then use `svn checkout --ignore-externals`.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing to skip some pre-built components in a previous job.

Comment: I don't understand what the `external repository` means. Can you explain it?

Comment: An external repository just means a different repository. You can set SVN properties on the original repository to bring in external content. The property is called "externals", hence that term.

Answer (score 3):

I found this question looking for a way to check out the WebKit sources while excluding the regression tests. I ended up with the following:

```
svn checkout http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk WebKit \
  --depth immediates

cd WebKit
find . \
  -maxdepth 1 -type d \
  -not -name '.*' \
  -not -name '*Tests' \
  -not -name 'Examples' \
  -not -name 'Websites' \
  | (while read SUBDIR; do svn update --set-depth infinity "$SUBDIR"; done)
```

Note you can change the exclusions as you see fit, but .* is recommended to skip the working directory (which is already up to date) and all of the .svn directories.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: these are unix shell commands (they can also be saved and executed as a script file)

Answer (score 2):

I have recently resolved the same task.
The idea is to get the immediate list of folder/files under the repository exclude the entries you need, then check out the remaining folders and update the immediate files if any.
Here is the solution:

```
    # Path to the svn repository to be checked out
rpath=https://svn-repo.company.com/sw/trunk/ && \
    # This files are to be excluded (folders are ending with '/')
    # this is a regex pattern with OR ('|') between enties to be excluded
excludep='docs_folder/tests_folder/|huge_folder/|file1|file2' && \
    # Get list of the files/folders right under the repository path
filtered=`svn ls $rpath | egrep -v $excludep` && \
    # Get list of files out of filtered - they need to be 'uped'
files=`echo $filtered | sed 's| |\n|g' | egrep '^.*[^/]$'` && \
    # Get list of folders out of filtered - they need to be 'coed'
folders=`echo $filtered | sed 's| |\n|g' | egrep '^.*[/]$'` && \
    # Initial nonrecursive checkout of repository - just empty
    # to the current (./) working directory
svn co $rpath ./ --depth empty && \
    # Update the files
svn up $files &&\
    # Check out the all other folders finally.
svn co `echo $folders | sed "s|\<|$rpath|g"`
```

Change to source working directory. Copy the commands. Paste. Change appropriate URL and exclude pattern. Run the command.

Thanks,

Comment: hey what's 6 years for developers? On your last line you have $ubrpath. Where is that set?

Comment: @D-Klotz, thank you, that should be $rpath instead, which in turn is set to the repository path.
<br/>Sorry for one year late

Answer (score 1):

No, ignore is only for adding files.
You can use sparse checkouts (if you use svn 1.5)

Answer (score 1):

As a few others have mentioned, you can just use svn:externals properties and then the --ignore-externals option when you checkout.  One thing to note, however, is that svn:externals does *not* necessarily need to refer to another repository.  It can be a reference to some other folder in the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have seen is to check out a zero depth version and then go into the directories you need to change and update the depth.

Checking out a zero depth folder

```
$ svn co svn://subversion/project/my_project_dir --depth immediates
```

Then going into the working folders and adding depth

```
$ cd my_project_dir
$ cd working_dir && svn update --set-depth infinity
```

Update as many folders as you need to work on!