# Ignoring protected folders on SVN checkout

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I am having the following problem: Our svn repo has externals, and one subdirectory of the externals is not accessible with my credentials (the externals are managed by a different team). If I do an SVN checkout with Tortoise, I get prompted for user/pw and can just cancel this and it will continue with the next folder.

However, if I do a command-line checkout (this runs inside a C# program) the program fails after hitting a set timeout barrier. I never see any prompt (and even if it did appear, that wouldn't be helpful, as this program runs as an automated process).

Is there some commend-line option for svn with which I can just ignore folders for which I am lacking checkout permissions and have it continue with the next directory?

Comment: I dont know about the SVN, but in TFS there is.

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn

Comment: Possible duplicate, since you know the exact folder you want to avoid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192824/svn-checkout-ignore-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options of `svn co`

```
  --depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
                             'immediates', or 'infinity')
```

or

```
  --ignore-externals       : ignore externals definitions
```

may help