# Skip directory in SVN checkout? (Partial checkout)

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

Suppose a remote SVN repository has this structure:

```
/project
        /src
        /bulk
```

Now for some reason I already have a copy of `bulk` (assumed unchanging or rarely changing) elsewhere on my machine. Can I somehow checkout a new copy of the repository, but pre-provide the `bulk` directory so it doesn't get downloaded again?

To clarify, this hypothetical process should certainly check the checksums on the files in the `bulk` directory and update those files which aren't correct, so that ultimately I'll have a complete, consistent checkout. I just want to shortcut past downloading those files which I already have verbatim.

Comment: I don't think so but more importantly that leads to the problem that your svn repo is no longer authoritative. In addition what about others (including your future self - on another machine) who don't have the now magic bulk. What exactly is bulk? Data, 3rd party library it might help us direct you to a best practice.

Comment: @SteveRobillard: The magic bulk is part of the repo (say it's a collection of sountrack files). I just happen to have downloaded those already, and I want to take advantage of that. I'm very happy for checksums to be verified and all this!

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192824/svn-checkout-ignore-folder

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Checkout /project, specifying the depth to be 'empty'.
2. Update /project/src specifying infinite depth.
3. Copy your current bulk working copy into the project directory working copy.

e.g.

```
svn checkout --depth empty http://svnserver/project/ project
svn update --set-depth infinity project/src
// copy your current /bulk into /project
```

Note - this takes advantage of the [sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) feature introduced in Subversion 1.5.

Comment: Could you spell this out a bit further for a complete SVN newbie? :-)

Comment: If `/bulk` isn't changing, and you don't intend to check it out from the repo, there's no need for it to be in the repo.  Just keep your `/src` folder in the repo.

Comment: @bdares: It's not my repo, though! :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Quick, now's your chance to skip SVN and get on the Hg/Git/Foo wagon! ;-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: which SVN client are you using?

Comment: @pst: LOL - I couldn't agree more! ;-)

Comment: (Practically, I'm talking about the `trunk/sc2/content` directory of the *[Ur-Quan Masters](http://sc2.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sc2/)* repository. Any suggestions for change of RCS should be directed to the project leads who cannot be thanked enough for their work.)

Comment: To see the tree, with empty subdirs: `svn checkout --depth immediates http://svnserver/project/ project` ... and then `cd` to what you need and `svn update --set-depth infinity` within the empty subdir.

Comment: @stevesliva `immediates` - nice tip

Answer (score 1):

Instructions when using **TortoiseSVN** 1.7 and newer:

1. "SVN Checkout" to /project, specifying "Checkout Depth" as "Only this item"
2. "SVN Checkout" to /project/trunk, specifying "Checkout Depth" as "Fully recursive"

Answer (score -1):

Last time I had to do this, I had an enormous number of demo files in a directory, and I just moved these to a new directory out of `trunk`.

You might consider doing something similar, and adding `bulk` to `svn:ignore`, if you need `bulk` to be in the same directory.

Comment: So you mean I should decouple the `bulk` from revision control and just use my local copy for my local machine? I guess that's a workaround, though I was really hoping to be able to "seed" my checkout with the local files.

Comment: No, `bulk` would remain in version control, but not in `trunk`. This way you will be able to avoid a large check-out.