# Delete old SVN files from the ".svn/pristine" folder

Tags: svn, repository

I have an SVN repository with a folder called `archives`, and this folder contains more than 3 GB of files.

Now, I don't need this folder for working (I've uploaded it to the SVN repository because of a mistake. These files are required only on the running application, not the source).

I've deleted the folder (`svn rm ...`), and, now my working copy have 3 GB less space used (the space from the archives folder deleted), but the `.svn/pristine` folder from the parent maintains the same used space.

How can I delete / clean this folder? I don't need this cache at the local working copy.

Comment: Does your working copy contain the archives folder still? Did you commit the `svn rm` to the server?

Comment: No,  I doesn't have the folder, and the rm are commited two versions ago.

Answer (score 3):

Run `svn cleanup`.  This will cause SVN to remove files from the .svn folder that are no longer being tracked by your working copy.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028557/1698557) from one of the SVN developers.

Comment: svn cleanup doesn't clean these folder. I've tried all options (from tortoiseSVN), i've lost even my .idea folder, but the .svn folder mantains it's size on 3gb.