# SVN Externals odd behaviour

Tags: apache, svn

I've gotten this to work with another project just before but it's absolutely refusing to do it now and I'm not sure as to why. Here is what I'm doing:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/branches/3.9-branch .
```

then...

```
svn update —set-depth=exclude wp-content
rm -fr wp-content
```

lastly...

```
svn propset svn:externals “wp-content” http://svn.example.com.au/site/ wp-content/
```

Every time I try and run svn externals it continuely keeps saying the following:

> svn: E200009: Cannot mix repository and working copy targets

Which makes zero sense because I have done the exact same with another project just before and it didn't give me no such errors.

I'm going out of my mind.

Thank you very much for anyones help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my solution. My command line was incorrect. (and I hate Mondays)

```
svn propset svn:externals "wp-content http://svn.example.com.au/site/" .
```

Comment: Just two additional notes: 1) `--set-depth exclude` is formal syntax 2) `--set-depth exclude TARGET` will remove target from WC immediatelly, `rm -rf` not needed at all

Comment: @LazyBadger I'm still green behind the ears when it comes to SVN. Thank you very much for letting me know I've chucked this into my SVN command snippets. I came across --set-depth=exclude from a stackoverflow post, here is the link for anyone else who might be interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192824/svn-checkout-ignore-folder#answer-8446590