# Selective SVN checkout based on pattern

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I'm trying to partially checkout a large SVN repository that contain lots of files I don't need: object files, `.class` files, sound and other data files. These files may occur in any directory.

I'm tired of going through all the subdirs in the repo browser to see whether I need to check them out recursively or sparsely. Does SVN offer a way to checkout only files that match or don't match a (regex, glob or other) pattern?

Comment: Have a look at that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192810/svn-checkout-filtered-by-file-extension/2023917#2023917

Comment: Do you need to checkout the entire repository? That is not typical in svn - at the very least, you'd normally be checking out a branch (e.g., trunk). Also, class files and other generated files don't usually belong in source control - that's perhaps a separate issue to tackle.

Comment: @Joshua: I need just the trunk. (I'm used to git, excuse me for misusing terminology.) I fully agree that `class` files should not be in the repo, but I don't control that and don't intend to get in control.

Comment: I figured as much (re: git) - I'm afraid I don't know of a way to get around the problem in svn :/

Answer (score 1):

Not directly in svn, no. See ( [Can you do a partial checkout with Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945/can-you-do-a-partial-checkout-with-subversion) ).

You'd have to do a checkout at empty depth, then in your own script, update the files that match a pattern