# SVN - get a part of the revision

Tags: svn

I'm looking for a way to get all files of some type (e.g. all .java files) from a repository, without downloading all of the files (so it can be fast). How can it be done?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192810/svn-checkout-filtered-by-file-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a small shell script that parses the output of `svn list -R $URL` and exports only the relevant files with `svn export $URL+PATH+FILENAME`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify a common subdirectory, why not just checkout that sub-directory?

Comment: I'm interested in cases where there is no common sub-directory, and the files are spread among hundreds of directories.