# Partial SVN checkout and update depending on properties

Tags: svn, version-control, properties, sparse-checkout

Is it possible to use SVN properties to mark files/folders necessary to compile and run a part of a larger project. E.g. "config1:used" "config2:unused". i would like to do something like (Pseudocommand):

```
svn checkout URL[@REV] PATH .where "property:config1==used"
svn update             PATH .where "property:config1==used"
```

I know about sparse checkout with svn, however it seems as this would be rather complicated to do with this features. I have read about [svn checkout filtered by file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192810/svn-checkout-filtered-by-file-extension). But this is not really answered and the same.

I could get all properties from the svn recursivly, filter, and checkout only the files where condition is true. But this is slow. Update will be very slow compared to normal checkout, as I could not find how to get only a update of the proplist. If I checkout single files, update won't work properly. Sparse directories with the --set-depth=exclude option seem to delete the local files, but not the data in the .svn-directory. So lot of disk space is used.

Comment: `svn:externals`? In "super"-projects, which are only wrappers for included fules/folders

Comment: Nice idea actually, we use externals anyway, but not exactly what i require. First, we have the properties anyway, externals for configurations would require to maintain a second structure. Secondly, I would also like to combine filtering on several properties with boolean operator, which will probably not work with externals.